# React native app crashes on receiving notification with error message "There is no completion handler with completionHandlerId:<Id>"

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios

I am trying to integrate react-native-firebase to a simple App. I followed the steps mentioned here http://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/installation-ios?id=_11-initialisation. I configured everything and run the app, but when I get notification from fcm app crashes with above-mentioned error message and it happens in RNFirebaseMessaging.m line number 406,
the code looks like this

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(finishRemoteNotification: (NSString *)completionHandlerId fetchResult:(UIBackgroundFetchResult)result) {
    RCTRemoteNotificationCallback completionHandler = self.notificationCallbacks[completionHandlerId];
    if (!completionHandler) {
        RCTLogError(@"There is no completion handler with completionHandlerId: %@", completionHandlerId);
        return;
    }
    completionHandler(result);
    [self.notificationCallbacks removeObjectForKey:completionHandlerId];
}
```

I did print completionHandler dictionary before this method is called and it has data but when this method is called completionHandler is nil.
Has anyone come across the same issue?

I am using react native version 0.47.0 and react-native-firebase 2.0.5
PS: App crashes every time it receives remote notification.

Comment: May I recommend making an issue on the github repo for RNFirebase, happy to take a look at it over there.

Answer (score 3):

As written [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/73#issuecomment-338188391)

The problem is that you are probably subscribing to 2 (or more) onMessage listeners.

When you call onMessage it will return unsubscribe method which you can call later if you need to and then subscribe again afterword.

Also, they are currently working on [Messaging / FCM overhaul](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/595)

```js
// subscribe
const unsubscribe = firebase.messaging().onMessage((url) => {
  // ...
});

// unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```